# Changing description of layer using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, layers

I would like to change the file description with a python code on ArcMap (10.6). I could not find a way to do it or resource explaining it.

Do you have any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Layer - ArcGIS Desktop Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm).

```
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
lyr.description = "This is the description of this layer"
```

Comment: Thank you @Midavalo . I figured how to work this out but also realized that is not what I wanted. I do not have a map file (.mxd) or layer file (.lyr). I have bunch of raster files that I want to put the same description for each of them. I guess it involves with metadata manipulation. As far as I understand this method creates a layer or read layers from a map document. For example, if I send my original file (.img) to somebody without the layer file, he will not see the description I created, right?

Comment: @OguzSariyildiz Correct.  Also if you send the original `.img` file to somebody without the metadata file, he will not see the description.

Comment: I cant get this to work from within ArcMap. I need to set the description of all layers in a document. I've tried saving the mxd, save a copy, export the layer to lyr. The description is not set. Do you know why?

Comment: @BERA I wonder if there's been a change in the syntax since 2018?  I'll take a look next time I'm at my PC and see what happens for me.